# Padding an integer month in sql?

Tags: sql

I have column stsmm which is a month integer. I need it in the form of MM.

I tried this: `RIGHT('0' || cast(stsmm as char(2)), 2)` but it does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Needs to be `RIGHT('0' || cast(stsmm as varchar(2)), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
select right(cast(100 + yourmonthcolumn as char(3)), 2)
```

This way always return in MM